# Responsive Web Navigation Menu (with images)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navigation, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create a responsive web site. I have used twitter bootstrap in the past and have also looked at foundation, however neither of the Navigation Menus behave as I would like.

I am looking to see if anyone can recommend a framework or template that will get the behaviour I would like.

Basically - this is how my menu would appear on a maximized browser :

[image: full web page navigation menu]

Clicking the coloured rectangle next to the link would also navigate to the desired page.

On a mobile I would like the page to appear like this : 
[image]

Site Logo would resize dynamicaly depending on mobile screen size - as would the coloured rectangles - but the main idea is that when the screen reaches a certain width the text beside the links on the 'Full View' would disappear and the rectangles would move to below the page logo.

All responsive web templates and frameworks seem to prefer a 'collapsed menu' approach which I think is just adding an extra touch or click to carry out a particular piece of functionality.

Comment: This is possible with bootstrap,you have to use `col-xs-*`, if u can show your code can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">Site Logo</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">Link A</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">Link B</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">Link C</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">Link D</div>
```

This must work

Answer (score 0):

The first answer will work if you style it appropriately.

E.g.

```
.colmd4  {
  width: 50%'
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  }

.col-md-2 {
  width: 12%;
  display: inline;
  padding: auto;
```

Remember that fingers are blunt, and that having 4 items on a screen width is about as close as you can pack them.

Another way you can do this, assuming the same 5 divs.

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px){
    div {
        display: inline;
        padding: 2em;
        }
    }
```

This will assume that the divs display block style for the mobile.

The extra padding makes them bigger targets for fingers.